# Illustrator reducing double stroke svg to a single stroke svg

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, svg, stroke, laser-cutting

I have a double stroke svg that I want to reduce to a single stroke svg. The area on the svg is defined as some white shapes that are overlayed on a black background, with anchors outlining the shapes and background.

[image]

*I hope this makes sense*

I almost want something like the monoline tool developed for text, so that I can simplify an icon to a single line svg for a lazer cutter.

Thanks.

Here's the closest thing I can get to a single line:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `Offset Path` effect to give you the look of a single line but it would still be compound when expanded. If nothing else, that gives you something accurate to trace over.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a "monoline" method developed for text - I've never heard of it, but was in need for one and came up with a method that most likely should do what you need:

[image: HowTo convert outlines to monoline]

Single Steps involved:

- Select Object, in case of text:
  **Type** -> **Create Outline Stroke** [Strg+Shift+O]
- Resize to a good size and Rasterize with high dpi (e.g. 300dpi):
  **Object** -> **Rasterize**
- **Image Trace** the resulting object, using the **Image Trace Panel** and selecting **Outline** as method.
- **Expand** the resulting ***Image Trace Object***

You then have a single stroke from complex double strokes/compound paths etc. It is not a "clean" method and results may vary (greatly!) with size of the rasterized object. Changing size has a much larger impact (rather than changing parameters of the Image Trace).

Comment: Instead of posting the exact same answer on different questions, just post once and flag the other questions as duplicate.